# calculate the sum of each column in sql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the sum of each row in mysql and display in php.

for eg

> amount1 | amount2 |  total   100     |   200   |
>
> 300     |   200   |

How to display the total of each column?
Here is the code. My code displays the whole table total and displays. What is the wrong with the code.

```
$query="SELECT *, sum(amount1+amount2) as total FROM contribution";
 $run = mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row['uid'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['Date'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['month1'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['amount1'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['month2'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['amount2'] ?></td><td><?php echo $row['total'] ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: `$query="SELECT *, amount1+amount2 as total FROM contribution";`

Comment: `SUM` is an aggregate function. You should be able to use `SELECT *, amount1 + amount2 AS total FROM contribution`.

Comment: how to display it in php

Comment: `<?php echo $row['total'] ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query as

```
"SELECT *, amount1+amount2 AS total FROM contribution;"
```

And to display the same in php, while going through each row to print total you can acess it as `$row['total']`